# Subreport does not paginate

Tags: ms-access, pagination, subreport

I am creating a report in access 2013 that has two sub reports. The sub reports are located at the detail section of main report. They are not stacked but tabular (placed side by side in the detail section). I have inserted page breaks inside each sub reports. But they don't seem to work. All the contents of try to show continuously. Thus overflowing into the page footer. I have also inserted a page break where the subreport control ended in the detail section of main report. **If I keep a small white space after the pagebreak in the mian report the sureports seems to be paginating , but leaves a blank page at the end of the report**. Both of the subreports generated from the same table with linked Child & master fields. Could any one suggest how to paginate the subreports without the blank page at the end ? Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Got My solution. this is - click the detail section bar>>>Force new page After Section. and then remove the page break control from the detail section of the main form. Keep no white space.
[Force new page after section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITkML.png)